# SMS: Apple has detected multiple failed login attempts

Tags: phishing, sms

I have just got a SMS message (text message) on my phone saying:

> Apple has detected multiple failed login attempts

Given I don't have (and have never had) an iPhone, I expect it is some sort of scam. However scammers are not well known for using a messaging system that they have to pay for and that is traceable to the sender.

So

- Should I report it to anyone (I am in the UK)?
- How are they getting round the networks being able to trace the phone that sent the SMS message?

Comment: [SMS spoofing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SMS_spoofing) exists. I don't know how hard (or easy) it is to carry out nowadays though.

Comment: Is there a link or anything else in the SMS? Or is it sent from a premium number (they're hoping for you to call back). Otherwise I can't understand the purpose of this scam.

Comment: @AndréBorie, there is a link in the message, it goes to a web page that ask for a password.

Comment: @AndréBorie, I get 100s of phishing attempts using email, this is the first I have had with SMS.

Answer (score 1):

This could be sent from a hacked phone server, hacked phone account for sending sms, or from a service that has unlimited sms.

Is this the literal message? Is this all that was in the message? If I google for this (with quotes) I don't get a result back.

Do you see a number or name? Google it and post it here.